# What should I do if my thesis advisor keeps insisting on making changes that are scientifically inaccurate?

Tags: thesis

My thesis advisor keeps proposing changes that are inaccurate (e.g change a scientific definition) or simply wrong. I have already gone through over 70 papers in order to find evidence and information about my subject. Still, when presented with evidence, my advisor keeps rejecting some ideas and has been rude at times. At the beginning of our collaboration she presented me three papers, out of which only one was relevant.

Her English is also not very good, so I'm starting to think she doesn't really know what she's talking about at all. Should I ignore her proposals completely? Anyone with similar experiences?

Comment: I love that your profile self-describes you as "Brilliant scientist!".

Comment: I guess your choices are, switch advisors, or work on developing a more mutually respectful relationship with this one, and finding ways of calmly defending your position.